Azure Web App doesn't send email using Azure Communication Email
I have a .net backend with react on frontend, when i click on a button from client side it should trigger an api that will put data in the db and then send an email. On local host everything works fine, i have followed the documentation from microsoft to configure azure. It has also a custom domain, but on the deployed web app with azure devops, it doesn't want to send it, and i don't understand what i miss and how can i fix it.
This is a part of my email service, and as i said, on local host works just fine.
        public EmailService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var endpoint = configuration["EmailService:CommunicationServicesEndpoint"];
            var tenantId = configuration["EmailService:TenantId"];
            var clientId = configuration["EmailService:ClientId"];
            var clientSecret = configuration["EmailService:ClientSecret"];

            _emailSettings = configuration.GetSection("EmailService:AccountingDepartment").Get<EmailSettings>()!;

            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            _emailClient = new EmailClient(new Uri($"https://{endpoint}.communication.azure.com/"), credential);
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(
            string subject,
            string htmlContent,
            List<string> toRecipients,
            List<string> ccRecipients,
            List<string> bccRecipients,
            string senderAddress,
            List<string> replyToAddresses)
        {
            var emailContent = new EmailContent(subject)
            {
                Html = htmlContent
            };

            var toEmailAddresses = toRecipients.Where(email => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)).Select(email => new EmailAddress(email)).ToList();
            var ccEmailAddresses = ccRecipients?.Where(email => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)).Select(email => new EmailAddress(email)).ToList() ?? [];
            var bccEmailAddresses = bccRecipients?.Where(email => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)).Select(email => new EmailAddress(email)).ToList() ?? [];

            var emailRecipients = new EmailRecipients(toEmailAddresses, ccEmailAddresses, bccEmailAddresses);

            var emailMessage = new EmailMessage(senderAddress, emailRecipients, emailContent);

            if (replyToAddresses != null)
            {
                foreach (var replyToAddress in replyToAddresses.Where(email => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)))
                {
                    emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add(new EmailAddress(replyToAddress));
                }
            }

            try
            {
                var emailSendOperation = await _emailClient.SendAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, emailMessage);

                string operationId = emailSendOperation.Id;
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to send email.", ex);
            }
        }

Sending email is used like a method, not like an endpoint:                     _emailService.SendMoneyRequestApprovalEmailAsync(requestedBy, requestedForDriver, requestedForTruck, amount, requestedFor, description);

You're going to need to provide some more information regarding your issue. Can you attach ApplicationInsights to the app published in Azure and then check the error logs?
Also... I"m assuming that you're actually doing: await _emailService.SendMoney.... Otherwise, the app is most likely disposing of your EmailService before actually performing the send operation.

@NerdyStudent Are you using an external custom domain or an Azure custom domain?

@NerdyStudent  make sure  to add appSettings in your yml file like below  example add - task: AzureWebApp@1   displayName: test   inputs:     appName:      azureSubscription:      appType:     appSettings: test=vivek

@AsleshaKantamsetti I'm using a custom domain.
akseli Unfortunately i don't have app insights activated for my service.
PS: The problem seems that is fixed, it was because of how i pass the email from env variables. For email receivers i'm ussing array, how i was passing was EmailService:Department : [john.doe@mail.com] , but it should be EmailService:Department[0] : john.doe@mail.com.

@NerdyStudent can you post it as answer so helps Other . you are right you add in env or add appSettings of yml file or app setting/configue setting of the azure.

@Sampath sure, thank you

The problem seems that is fixed, it was because of how I pass the email from env variables. For email receivers I'm using array, how I was passing was EmailService:Department : [john.doe@mail.com], but it should be EmailService:Department[0] : john.doe@mail.com.
